# How to find out the number for the div clicked (5th, 11th, 15th etc) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have 10 images in a div. If I click on the 6th one, how can I get the int value of the number 6 (or what ever the order was for the image)?
Is it possible?
I need it to navigate to the next image using `.get(currentindex+1)`

Don't advise me to use gallery plugins or anything please, I need to do this my way ^^

A helpful answer would be `var currentindex = >something useful<`

Comment: Are you saying that you've got a set of `div`s, with each `img` in its own `div`?

Comment: Nah, I had them all in one div, I can work with selectors, I just never used `index()` before, silly me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("div img").on("click", function (e) {
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/index/

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UE7AC/)

Comment: NB. The 6th one, for example, should have an index of 5.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, the word index didn't even come to my mind, which is why I didn't get anything from Google. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, use `.index()`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R8Zra/

Demo Code:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>

$('div').click(function(){
   alert($(this).index()+1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `<div/>` contains other elements besides `<img/>`s, make sure you pass the `'img'` selector to the `index()` function, or the numbering will be off.

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var currentindex = $(this).index('img');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j9C8/)